# How to get all the elements from the tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How to get all the title and the count (6) from all the elements

i need to get the values

Rs. 2000 - Rs. Below
Rs. 2001 - Rs. 5000
Rs. 5001 - Rs. 10000
Rs. 10001 - Rs. 18000 
Rs. 18001 - Rs. 25000 
Rs. 25001 - Rs. 35000 
Rs. 35001 and Above

and the values 6 34 41 12 15 9  4

Below is the html

```
<div class="body">
<div class="oneFacet bmargin5">
<input class="expandedContent dont-show" type="text">
<div class="loading"></div>
<div class="head line">
<ul id="price_range" class="facets" nofilter="1" displaytype="" keepcollapsed="" valuelimit="">
<li class="facet" title="Rs. 2000 and Below">
<a class=" active ">
<input class="facetoption" type="checkbox" value="facets.price_range%5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below" autocomplete="off">
<span class="title fk-inline-block lmargin5" original="Rs. 2000 and Below">Rs. 2000 and Below</span>
<span class="count">(6)</span>
</a>
</li>
 <li class="facet" title="Rs. 2001 - Rs. 5000">
<a class=" active ">
<input class="facetoption" type="checkbox" value="facets.price_range%5B%5D=Rs.+2001+-+Rs.+5000" autocomplete="off">
<span class="title fk-inline-block lmargin5" original="Rs. 2001 - Rs. 5000">Rs. 2001 - Rs. 5000</span>
<span class="count">(34)</span>
</a>
</li>

    <li class="facet" title="Rs. 5001 - Rs. 10000">
    <li class="facet" title="Rs. 10001 - Rs. 18000">
    <li class="facet" title="Rs. 18001 - Rs. 25000">
    <li class="facet" title="Rs. 25001 - Rs. 35000">
    <li class="facet" title="Rs. 35001 and Above">
    </ul>
    </div>
```

iam using the below code

```
WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.oneFacet bmargin5 ul"));
    List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for (WebElement li : lis) {
     System.out.println("names "+li.getText());
    }
```

but getting the error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.oneFacet bmargin5 ul"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.10 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'VALUED-8JGOG5PH', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 98a38901-4a9b-4aef-8823-b96f9043f5ad
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=26.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
etc....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.oneFacet bmargin5 ul"}

This can mean, the selector used was wrong **or** the element with this selector was not found. But in your case the problem is with the selector that you've used.

```
   div.oneFacet bmargin5 ul
```

This is a wrong way to specify multiple class names, use `period` to separate each class name instead of `space` i.e.,

```
   div.oneFacet.bmargin5 ul
```

Moreover,  ul has an `id`, using this would be a better option.

```
   WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.id("price_range"));
```

or

```
   WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#price_range"));
```

Comment: Thanks Amith for explaing clearly. problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect, also you are not printing the correct data as per your requirement. Use **ID** to search ul, as it is the fastest way. Moreover, you need to get two separate text value, for that you have to try following:

```
WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.id("price_range"));
List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement li : lis) {
    System.out.println("1st part: "+li.getAttribute("title")); //To get "Rs. 2001 - Rs. 5000"
    System.out.println("2nd part: "+li.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='count']")).getText()); //To get the count "(6)", if you want just "6" you can manipulate the string fetched.
}
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks Husam, for the code,  but one problem with the findelement it is printing same count(6), i will check that.

Comment: You are saying that 1st part is printing correctly for each li, but 2nd part is same?? As per the html provided by you I could not find any problem in my xpath. Is the Html accurate?? Can you provide complete html or URL??

Comment: Hi, Here is the Link for that http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?p[]=facets.features%255B%255D%3DGSM&p[]=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=73999cf8-c1a3-40d0-afb8-7b889f60e227  . you can see the Price under that the count is there,

Comment: Found it, there a little mistake in 2nd xpath. To look into child of a node we have to start with **./**. I have corrected the 2nd xpath in code above. It should work fine now :). _Also, you can accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you_

Comment: . symbol Selects current node, if any further path is provided (as in our case), it starts looking from current node. On the other hand // Selects nodes in the document that match the selection no matter where they are. Hence we had given only // it returned 6 each time,  but when we added . at beginning it looked inside the respective node (li) each time.